# Building own recursive power function

Tags: python, recursion

I'm pretty new to python as a whole so apologies, but i'm tasked with building a standalone power function for exponents upto 4.

So far i have;

```
def power(x,n):
    if(n==1):
        return x
    if(n==2):
        return square(x)
    if(n==3):
        return cube(x)
    if(n==4):
        return hypercube(x)
```

with the square, cube and hypercube functions being;

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

def cube(x):
    return x*x*x

def hypercube(x):
    return x*x*x*x
```

I'm trying to replace the square, cube and hypercube functions with calls to the power function itself, but i'm having trouble understanding recursive call. I tried the following thinking you just have to call from within directly to the end result. I'm struggling just being able to visualise this

```
def power(x,n):
    if(n==1):
        return x
    if(n==2):
        return power(x^)
    if(n==3):
        return power(x^n)
    if(n==4):
        return power(x^n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use direct recursion like so

```
def power(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return x * power(x, n - 1)
```

Comment: @JonClements x ^ 0 == 1?

Comment: @JonClements: No, its zero-th power

Comment: Ugh... sorry folks - think my brain went on strike there for a moment :)